# How to use tab to move in a list of fields in Red language

Tags: user-interface, rebol, red

This is similar to my earlier question ( [Using TAB to move between fields in Red language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922423/using-tab-to-move-between-fields-in-red-language) ). Since I have many fields, I want to use a list of fields. However, following code is not working:

```
Red []

view [
    text "Value of x:"  f1: field "" on-key [handle-key event] return
    text "Value of y:"  f2: field "" on-key [handle-key event] return
    text "Third: " f3:  field "" on-key [handle-key event] return
    text "Fourth:" f4:  field "" on-key [handle-key event] return
    text "Read Sum:"    tt: text ""  on-key [handle-key event] return
    do[
        fldlist: [f1 f2 f3 f4]
        focusnum: 1
        maxfocusnum: length? fldlist
        handle-key: function [e] [
            print rejoin ["focusnum = " focusnum]   ; OUTPUT: "focusnum = none"
            k: e/key
            if k = tab [
                either e/shift? 
                    [   focusnum: focusnum - 1
                        if focusnum < 1 [focusnum: maxfocusnum]
                        win/selected: fldlist/:focusnum]
                    [   focusnum: focusnum + 1
                        if focusnum > maxfocusnum [focusnum: 1]
                        win/selected: fldlist/:focusnum]
                        ] ] ]

    button "Calculate" [
        tt/text: to-string ((to-integer f1/text) + (to-integer f2/text))      
    ]
    button "Quit" [quit]  
    do [win: self win/selected: f1]
]
```

The `focusnum` is given out as `none`. Where is the problem and how can this be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two modifications make your script working

```
fldlist: [f1 f2 f3 f4] -> fldlist: reduce [f1 f2 f3 f4
```

You need the 'faces' and not the words pointing to the faces.

```
handle-key: function [e] [
```

->

```
 handle-key: func [e] [
     focusnum: index? find fldlist win/selected
```

**function** makes automatically all set-words local. Therefore the local **focusnum** is not initialized with a value, but the global focusnum has still the start value . Finding the focusnum dynamically should cure the 'disturbance'. Probably there are more efficent ways to do so.

And here an almost final version with proper **formatting**

```
view [
    text "Value of x:"  f1: field "" on-key [handle-key event]  on-focus [handle-focus face event] return
    text "Value of y:"  f2: field "" on-key [handle-key event] on-focus [handle-focus face event] return
    text "Third: " f3:  field "" on-key [handle-key event] on-focus [handle-focus face event] return
    text "Fourth:" f4:  field "" on-key [handle-key event] on-focus [handle-focus face event] return
    text "Read Sum:"    tt: text ""  on-key [handle-key event] return
    do[
        fldlist:  reduce [f1 f2 f3 f4]
        focusnum: 1
        maxfocusnum: length? fldlist
        handle-key: func [e] [
            print rejoin ["focusnum = " focusnum]  
            k: e/key
            if k = tab [
                either e/shift?   [   
                    focusnum: focusnum - 1
                    if focusnum < 1 [focusnum: maxfocusnum]
                    set-focus  fldlist/:focusnum
                ] [   
                    focusnum: focusnum + 1
                    if focusnum > maxfocusnum [focusnum: 1]
                    set-focus  fldlist/:focusnum
                ]
            ]
        ] 
        handle-focus: func [f e] [ probe focusnum: index? find fldlist f]
    ]
    button "Calculate" [
        tt/data:  f1/data + f2/data      
    ]
    button "Quit" [quit]  
    do [win: self win/selected: f1]
]
```

Comment: Yes, it works but everything gets disturbed if some field is manually selected by clicking mouse on it. Any way to correct this problem? I am not able to make `find` or `select fldlist win/selected` work for this.

Comment: This works very well. Great. I hope this feature comes in future release of language itself.

Answer (score 0):

I managed some further simplification of code:

```
view [
    text "Value of x:"  f1: field "" on-key [handle-key event] return
    text "Value of y:"  f2: field "" on-key [handle-key event] return
    text "Third: " f3:  field ""    on-key [handle-key event] return
    text "Fourth:" f4:  field ""    on-key [handle-key event] return
    text "Read Sum:"    tt: text "" on-key [handle-key event] return
    button "Calculate" [
        tt/data:  f1/data + f2/data   
    ]
    button "Quit" [quit]  

    do[ fldlist:  reduce [f1 f2 f3 f4]
        mafocusnumfocusnum: length? fldlist
        handle-key: func [e] [
            if e/key = tab [
                focusnum: index? find fldlist win/selected
                either e/shift?
                    [   focusnum: focusnum - 1    
                        if focusnum < 1 [focusnum: mafocusnumfocusnum] ]
                    [   focusnum: focusnum + 1    
                        if focusnum > mafocusnumfocusnum [focusnum: 1] ]
                set-focus fldlist/:focusnum 
            ]   
        ]
        win: self win/selected: f1
    ] 
]
```

handle-focus function is not needed here.

Comment: handle-focus is not needed as I showed in my answer at first, but the setting of focusnum at every key stroke is inefficent compared to the solution of setting at focus change.